# Jquery Mobile auto-refresh every X second

Tags: php, jquery-mobile

Jquery Mobile auto-refresh every X second

Porting to JQM and having trouble getting page that automatically refreshes content every X seconds to display properly.  Have read dozens of related threads but not finding a clear solution with code example.  The purpose of this page is to display arrival and departure information on something similar to what you might see in an airport.

Previous approach was as follows with javascript in the header.  PHP content (a styled table) would load to named DIV after one second then refresh every ten seconds automatically and worked great:

Controlling Page:

```
<head>....
<script type="text/javascript">
function Refresh_My_DynamicContent(){ 
  $("#id_My_DynamicContent").load("NewContent.php");
  setTimeout(function() { Refresh_My_DynamicContent(); },10000); 
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  setTimeout(function() { Refresh_My_DynamicContent(); },1000); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page">
<div id=” id_My_DynamicContent”></div>
</div>
```

When I use this same approach with JQM the content displays but without JQM, pop-ups all expanded, etc.  Could anyone please help direct me to the proper approach with JQM to have a “hands-off” display that refreshes on its own with code example?

Comment: use ajax calls to update page's content instead of refreshing entire page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code should be like

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        setTimeout(function() { 
          $("#id_My_DynamicContent").load("NewContent.php",{'reload':true});
        },1000); 
    });
    </script>
```

also check that after the first call is working
  I am not sure if jquery moble also relaces the all head if that is the case you should also 
echo the js from the PHP

```
<?php
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        setTimeout(function() { 
          $("#id_My_DynamicContent").load("NewContent.php",{'reload':true});
        },1000); 
    });
    </script>';
?>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing how this is different but will try this and update accordingly.  Thank you for the reply.

Comment: I think after loading the first time the js code is removed and you have to inject it again from your ajax source so in the second call it will call it again this is my assumption, also if you can provide URL of your code it will be easier to help you.

Comment: I also see there is reload params which is by default is false, you should try it also, I will edit my answer to show you how

Comment: sorry for the delayed response, had some crisis come up but solving this will be priority 1 this weekend.  The update makes sense and look forward to testing it out.  Thanks again for the assist regardless.